# Интеграция с Zoho CRM и вывод данных не из кастомных таблиц

Tags: php, интеграция, crm

Есть ли у кого-нибудь опыт интеграции с Zoho CRM? Итак, все по порядку:

**I**. Создал ACCESS_TOKEN через API Mode в данной CRM

**II**. Пытаюсь получить хоть какие-нибудь данные посредством кода, выложенного у них в качестве примера:

```
    header("Content-type: application/xml");
    $token = "my_token";
    $url = "https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/Clients/getRecords";
    $param= "newFormat=1&authtoken=".$token."&scope=crmapi";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $param);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
```

В ответ возвращается XML с `4600` ошибкой - `Unable to process your request. Please verify whether you have entered proper method name,parameter and parameter values.`

**III**. Поставил библиотеку `zoho-crm-client-php`, которая также на любые мои запросы возвращает пустые массивы в качестве результата, хотя при обращении к полям, возвращает список кастомных полей в кастомных модулях:

```
$client = new ZohoCRMClient('Leads', 'my_token');

$records = $client->getFields()->request();
```

**IV**. Собственно вопрос: что я делаю не так, учитывая, что мне нужно получить данные не из кастомных модулей, а с клиентского (список вакансий)? Я так понял, для этого нужно использовать метод `getSearchRecordsByPDC`. Правильно ли это?

**V**. Второй вопрос - при обращении к нестандартному модулю нужно указывать `CustomModule1(2,3,4-N)`, но в ответ получаю сообщение о том, что данных модулей не существует, а при попытке обратиться по на названию `$client = new ZohoCRMClient('MyModule', 'my_token');` получаю снова `4600` ошибку.

**VI**. Если я такой рукожоп, что не могу сделать простую интеграцию из примеров, то что говорить уже о нестандартном модуле.

Comment: В их документации очень большая каша – примеры на разные продукты приведены на разные версии api и интерфейса.
Попробуй использовать другую библиотеку https://github.com/mctekk/zohocrm

Comment: @sergeydyadyul вопрос более не актуален, нужно вообще удалить его будет